# How to use Power with NumberForm?

Tags: formatting, output-formatting

Being in need of calculating the following numbers with 18 decimals of precision: $2^{2^{-x}}, x\in{\mathbb{N}}$.

I looked for what built-in symbols can help me and found [Power](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Power.html) and [NumberForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm.html). I tried an example:

```
NumberForm[Power[2, 2^-3], 18]
```

But when evaluated, it shows up like $2^{1/8}$, whereas I wanted $1.090507732665257659$. How can I make WolframCloud use the latter formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out shortly after posting the question. I should have used the [N](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) built-in symbol rather than `NumberForm`. Rewriting the code snippet to make it work:

```
N[Power[2, 2^-3], 18]
```

I may have been able to keep using `NumberForm` if I wanted to by wrapping the `Power[...]` expression within `N`, but it looks like `N` suffices for I needed to do.